# What happens when we divide zero by zero?

Tags: arithmetic

I know that 0/any number=0 and any number/0=no answer, (negative) infinity, undefined.  So, what happens if we divide zero by itself?  Is it zero?  Is it infinity?  Well, infinity isn't a real number, but let's cut to the real chase.  Let's say there are two points on a coordinate plane put together.  How will we know what line to draw?  What slope does it have?  We know that the x- and y-intercepts are the same.  What happens when we divide zero by zero?

Comment: Divsion by zero is not defined because zero does not have a multiplicative inverse.  It follows from the ring axioms that $0x=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and therefore there is no $y\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $0y=1$.

Comment: The universe implodes into itself. Don't try it!

Comment: I don't care...

Comment: The derivative in calculus is all about dividing tiny things by tiny things, in the limit as the tiny things become zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0/0 is undefined, but if you want a value, this is best done using limits. 0/0 can be approached in multiple ways.

First of all, there is the function x/x. The limit of this function as x goes to 0 is 1.

There is also 0/x, the limit of this function as x goes to 0 is 0.

And the last one I will discuss: x/0 as x goes to 0. This limit does not exist.

Of course, you can think of many more limits.

Comment: There is also $(\sin x)/x$ which approaches 1 if you use radians, or $\pi/180$ if you use degrees.

Comment: Yup, I personally like that limit a lot. Limits really are full of surprises. There is of course an infinite amount of limits we can think of to approach the problem of 0/0, but I just listed the three first ones I thought of.